# SwiftUI custom Facebook Login with FB app installed

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swiftui, facebook-login

I'm trying to build a custom fb login in my iOS app, which is built in SwiftUI.
The basic flow seems to work, I get a response when login gets cancelled. I even get a token when logging into the FB web interface, everything works fine for that.

The problem exists only when a user has the FB app on their phone (which is fairly common). My app initially opens the web interface, which then opens the native FB app. I log into the FB app, and it goes back to my app without my app seeing anything new.

The code below is the main login call. There is other code of course, but not sure what else is relevant. Remember, the login *does* work perfectly with the FB web interface, it only breaks with the FB app. Any help would be appreciated!

```
let permissions = ["email", "public_profile"]
loginManager.logIn(permissions: permissions, from: nil) { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Login failed")
        // deal with failure
    }
    else if result?.isCancelled != true {
        let token = result!.token
        // store token
    } else {
        print("Facebook login cancelled")
        // handle cancel
    }
}
```

Comment: When you app open with a URL scheme `application(_:open:options:)` should be called, I am sure Facebook passes the relevant data inside the URL as a parameter

Comment: (Assuming you are using the FBSDK pod) Do you have `ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` and `Profile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)` in your `AppDelegate`? Furthermore, can you paste your `application(_:open:options:)l` function, also in `AppDelegate`. And lastly, did you make sure your pod file is updated?

Comment: The facebook login doesn't seem to trigger the native app anymore, since the iOS 14 update, or possibly an update to the FB SDK? The result is that it now always uses the web login, which does work. So I guess the problem doesn't exist at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I got the solution.

You should add `.onOpenURL` in App.

```
    @main
struct yourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                      UIApplication.shared,
                      open: url,
                      sourceApplication: nil,
                      annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And Don't forget to add `import FBSDKCoreKit`